# Alfresco web service authentication

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco

I'm trying to connect to a remote Alfresco webservice using this java instrunction:

```
WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress(configFile.getProperty("WebServiceFactory"));

AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub authenticationService = (AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub) new AuthenticationServiceLocator().getAuthenticationService();
```

The authentication fails because the authority properties of AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub it's not remote URL but it's localhost:8080. How can I fix that?

the stack trace is:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/authentication/1.0}AuthenticationFault:<ns1:errorCode>100</ns1:errorCode><ns1:message>08290021 Failed to authenticate</ns1:message>
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}exceptionName:org.alfresco.repo.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationFault
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:
    at org.alfresco.repo.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationWebService.startSession(AuthenticationWebService.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1310.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)

    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:heisenberg.local


    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer.<init>(BeanDeserializer.java:90)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationFault.getDeserializer(AuthenticationFault.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getSpecialized(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.getDeserializerAs(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:464)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.getDeserializerForType(DeserializationContext.java:547)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.onStartChild(SOAPFaultDetailsBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1035)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.startSession(AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.java:187)
    at com.kipcast.health.Caller.main(Caller.java:60)
```

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: could you please post the stack trace?

Comment: That doesn't look like the whole stacktrace, and it doesn't include the exception details, any chance you could post all of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just put the webserviceclient.properties in the alfresco folder.
Check the SDK for webservice client samples.

Alfresco reads the following propertie:
repository.location=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api

Hence this is the remote Alfresco location.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write like following -

For Login -

`WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress("http://" + remoteHostIp + ":" + port + "/alfresco/api");`

AuthenticationUtils.startSession(strUserName, strPassword);

For Logout -

`AuthenticationUtils.endSession();`